# Heading div images should be displayed at a lower depth

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage where the top 25% of the page is the heading(with images in it) & the rest of the page has the content.

I am trying to get the heading div to display is pictures at a lower depth as the content div because currently the heading images overflow into the content div(intentionally) & when they do they mess up the positioning of the HTML elements in the content div.

**My code below should make the heading div display below the content div but it doesn't. Can you help me figure out why & how to fix it?**

My CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    body       { background-color: RGB(255, 255, 255); margin: 20px; text-align: center; }

    #outerContainer { background-color: #DCFF9A; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    #header         { width: 1200px; height: 25%;  background-color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; overflow: visible; z-index: -5; }
    #main           { display: block; width: 1200px; height: 60%; background-color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; z-index: 5; }
    #navBar         { float: left; height: 800px; width: 240px; background-color: red; } 
    #content        { float: left; height: 800px; width: 760px; background-color: yellow; }

    #kamaleiText    { float: left; }
    #kamaleiLogo    { float: left; padding-top: 30px; background-color: green; z-index: inherit; }
    #kamaleiLeaves  { float: right; z-index: -2; background-color: cyan; z-index: inherit; }
```

And my HTML is the following:

```
<body>

    <div id="outerContainer">

        <!-- Knowtice if I set the images width to something smaller then everything is spaced out correctly, so these elements are not being shown below others when they should be -->

        <div id="header">
            <img id="kamaleiLogo" src="" alt="Pic1" height="98%" width="300px"/>      
            <img id="kamaleiLeaves" src="" alt="Pic2" height="300px" width="300px"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="navBar">
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                abcdef
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: why does kamaleiLeaves specify z-index twice?

Answer (score 1):

can you check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apU4g/)

basically, i have made the `#outerContainer` and `#header` positioned relatively and increased the `z-index` for the header so it appears on top

then absolutely positioned pic1 and pic2 in the header so they overflow onto the main content

```
#outerContainer { position: relative; background-color: #DCFF9A; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
#header         { position: relative; width: 1200px; height: 25%;  background-color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; overflow: visible; z-index: 100; }
#kamaleiLogo    { position: absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-top: 30px; background-color: green; z-index: inherit; }
#kamaleiLeaves  { position: absolute; top:0; right:0; background-color: cyan; z-index: inherit; }
```

Answer (score 0):

@mack; in your `#main div` there are two `floated elements` so first `clear` it may be that's work for you

```
#main           { overflow:hidden;width: 1200px; height: 60%; background-color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; z-index: 5; }
```